# create customer rulers using when function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create custom rules with the "when" function to finally apply them on a column of a dataframe. Many of these rules will apply to different columns, but the idea is not to write them for each column else store them in a variable and concatenate. For example I have the following:

```
df
.withColumn("campoOut1",when(col("campo1") === "G" && col("campo2") === "00", "001"))
.withColumn("campoOut2",
    when(col("campo1") === "G" && col("campo2") === "00", "001").
    when(col("campo3") === "G" && col("campo4") =!= "00", "002"))
```

and I want to achieve the following :

```
val ruler1 = when(col("campo1") === "G" && col("campo2") === "00", "001")
val ruler2 = when(col("campo3") === "G" && col("campo4") =!= "00", "002")

 df.withColumn("campoOut1",ruler1)
   .withColumn("campoOut2",ruler1 + ruler2)
```

I have not been successful because the variables ruler1 and ruler2 are not of type "string", any idea how to do it?

beforehand thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could recursively chain the rules:

```
def chainRules(rules: (Column, String)*) = {
     def go(rules: Seq[(Column, String)], chained: Column): Column = {
        if (rules.isEmpty) {
           return chained
        }
        go(rules.tail, chained.when(rules.head._1, rules.head._2))
     }
     go(rules.tail, when(rules.head._1, rules.head._2))
  }
```

but you would need to adapt your rules like that:

```
val rule1 = (col("campo1") === "G" && col("campo2") === "00", "001")
val rule2 = (col("campo3") === "G" && col("campo4") =!= "00", "002")
```

than u can use it like that:

```
 df.withColumn("campoOut1", chainRules(rule1))
   .withColumn("campoOut2", chainRules(rule1, rule2))
```

Comment: Nice. One question, What does the asterisk mean after parenthesis? rules: (Column, String)*

Comment: its scalas version of variable arguments.

`def x(vars: String*) = println(x)`

lets you use x like that:

`x("multiple", "arguments", "in", "here")`

in the function itself it will be a `WrappedArray`

Comment: I get it, Is there another way to write the code without using "return"? the intellij Idea detects it as a bad practice

Comment: Wrap the second condition in an else, than you can remove the return